# Need modal form, to fetch all details from Mysql and display on it php table by java-script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-modal

*If i click on view button,it should display all details from mysql and display it in modal.Need javascript for view ,and(( `mysql is select * from tbl_name(user)`)) mysql code too.i am not much strong in javascript,php as i am new to it.Kindly help me with this.If i click on view button,it should display all details from mysql and display it in modal.Need javascript for view ,and(( mysql is `select * from tbl_name(user)`)) mysql code too.i am not much strong in javascript,php as i am new to it.Kindly help me with this  *

```js
var $table = $('table');
 $table.bootstrapTable({
     search: true,
     pagination: true,
     buttonsClass: 'primary',
     showFooter: true,
     minimumCountColumns: 2,
     columns: [{
             field: 'id',
             title: 'ID',
             sortable: true,
         }, {
             field: 'zonee',
             title: 'ZONEName',
             sortable: true,
         }, {
             field: 'location',
             title: 'LOCATION',
             sortable: true,
         },
         {
             field: 'pop_type',
             title: 'POP TYPE',
             sortable: true,
         },
         {
             field: 'switch_name',
             title: 'SWITCH NAME',
             sortable: true,
         },
         {
             field: 'switch_ip',
             title: 'SWITCH IP',
             sortable: true,
         },
         {
             field: 'switch_make',
             title: 'SWITCH MAKE ',
             sortable: true,
         },
         {
             field: 'switch_serial',
             title: 'SWITCH SERIAL',
             sortable: true,
         },
         {
             field: 'switch_model',
             title: 'SWITCH MODEL',
             sortable: true,
         },
         {

             title: 'OPERATIONS',
         },
         {
             field: 'operation',
             title: 'Action',
         },
     ],

 });



 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on('click', '.model_form', function() {
         $('#form_modal').modal({
             keyboard: false,
             show: true,
             backdrop: 'static'
         });
         var data = eval($(this).attr('data'));
         $('#id').val(data.id);
         $('#zonee').val(data.zonee);
         $('#location').val(data.location);
         $('#pop_type').val(data.pop_type);
         $('#switch_name').val(data.switch_name);
         $('#switch_ip').val(data.switch_ip);
         $('#switch_make').val(data.switch_make);
         $('#switch_serial').val(data.switch_serial);
         $('#switch_model').val(data.switch_model);
         $('#latitude').val(data.latitude);
         $('#longitude').val(data.longitude);
         if (data.id != "")
             $('#pop_title').html('Edit');
         else
             $('#pop_title').html('Add');
     });

     $(document).on('click', '.delete_check', function() {
         if (confirm("Are you sure to delete data")) {
             var current_element = $(this);
             url = "add_edit.php";
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: url,
                 data: {
                     ct_id: $(current_element).attr('data')
                 },
                 success: function(data) { //location.reload(); 
                     $('.' + $(current_element).attr('data') + '_del').animate({
                         backgroundColor: "#003"
                     }, "slow").animate({
                         opacity: "hide"
                     }, "slow");
                 }
             });
         }
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php $apage = array('id'=>'','name'=>'');?>
        <script>
            var page_0 = <?php echo json_encode($apage)?>
        </script>
        <h3><a data="page_0" class="model_form btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add new record</a></h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="table-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-sortable table-condensed  " cellspacing="0" width="100%" data-show-columns="true">
                <tbody>
                    <?php if(isset($result) && ($data_record) > 0)  : $i=1; ?>                      <?php  while ($users = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { ?>
                    <tr class="<?=$users->id?>_del">
                        <td>
                            <?=$i;?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?=$users->zonee;?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?=$users->location;?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?=$users->pop_type;?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?=$users->switch_name;?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?=$users->switch_ip;?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?=$users->switch_make;?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?=$users->switch_serial;?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?=$users->switch_model;?>
                        </td>

                        <td> <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=<?=$users->latitude;?>,<?=$users->longitude;?>" target=\ "_blank\"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0C8;</i></a></td>

                        <script>
                            var page_ <?php echo $users->id ?> = <?php echo json_encode($users);?>
                        </script>

                        <td><a data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id ?>" class="model_form btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>

                            <a data="<?php echo  $users->id ?>" title="Delete <?php echo $users->name;?>" class="tip delete_check btn btn-info btn-sm "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </a>

                            <a data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id ?>" class="model_form btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-view"></span></a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $i++; } ?>
                    <?php else : echo '<tr><td colspan="8"><div align="center">-------No record found -----</div></td></tr>'; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php
              if(isset($_SESSION['flash_msg'])) :  
               $message = $_SESSION['flash_msg'];
               echo $error= '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> <strong>'.$message.'</strong> </div>';
               unset($_SESSION['flash_msg']);
              endif;
          ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Form modal -->
<div id="form_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-paragraph-justify2"></i><span id="pop_title">ADD</span> POP INFORMATION</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- Form inside modal -->
            <form method="post" action="add_edit.php" id="cat_form">
                <div class="modal-body with-padding">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label>zonee :</label>
                                <input type="text" name="zonee" id="zonee" class="form-control required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label>location :</label>
                                <input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="form-control required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label>pop_type :</label>
                                <input type="text" name="pop_type" id="pop_type" class="form-control required number">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label>switch_name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="switch_name" id="switch_name" class="form-control required number">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label>switch_ip :</label>
                                <input type="text" name="switch_ip" id="switch_ip" class="form-control required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label>switch_make :</label>
                                <input type="text" name="switch_make" id="switch_make" class="form-control required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label>switch_serial :</label>
                                <input type="text" name="switch_serial" id="switch_serial" class="form-control required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label>switch_model :</label>
                                <input type="text" name="switch_model" id="switch_model" class="form-control required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label>Latitude:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="latitude" id="latitude" class="form-control required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <label>Longitude:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="longitude" id="longitude" class="form-control required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <span id="add">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="id">
              <button type="submit" name="form_data" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you get any error? can you share it as well

Comment: actually for view ,i didn t done any codings. i have no idea. i have just added view button,need to know concept to code javascript for view.

Comment: can u able to open the modal? onclick?

Comment: no.i cannot open modal form bcz on button i have added ,i didn t do any other coding for it.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '#getUser', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var uid = $(this).data('id'); $('#form_modal').hide(); 
$('#model_form').show(); 
$.ajax({
url: 'getuser.php',
type: 'POST',data: 'id='+uid,
dataType: 'json'
  })
  .done(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $('#form_modal').hide(); 
      $('#form_modal').show();
      $('#txt_zonee').html(data.first_zonee);   
      $('#modal-loader').hide();
  })
  .fail(function(){
      $('.modal-body').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> try again...')

Comment: this script now opening modal form but shows something wrong.not fetching details. getuser.php as follows:

 header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
   
     require_once 'config.php';
 
     if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
      
         $id = intval($_POST['id']);
         $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=:id";
         $stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query ); 
         $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
         $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);       
         echo json_encode($row);
         exit; 
     }

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provided much detail about "view" button so i am assuming its this part

```
<a data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id ?>" class="model_form btn btn-info btn-sm viewuser" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-view"></span></a>
```

as you can see i have assigned new class'"viewuser"' to  above.
so you want to show modal popup when someone click on above view button. Well simple Algorithm would be

1. use onclick() for 'viewuser' and capture the click
2. fetch the "data" attribute which will contains userid
3. do Ajax call (like you are doing above in case of delete) and fetch data for that user
4. Now you have the data, and display it in modal popup

some code related to above would be

```
 <script>
      $('.viewuser').click(function(){
          var userid=$(this).attr('data');

          url = "add_edit.php";
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: url,
                 data: {
                     userid: userid
                 },
                 success: function(data) {
                    //display data whatever way you wanted
                    // for modal popup you can do thi to show a modal popup
                    //$('#viewpopup').modal('show');
                 }
             });

      });
  </script>
```

Comment: <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" id="getUser" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click', '#getUser', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var uid = $(this).data('id'); // get id of clicked row
 $('#dynamic-content').hide(); // hide dive for loader
 $('#modal-loader').show();  // load ajax loader
 $.ajax({
      url: 'getuser.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'id='+uid,
      dataType: 'json'
  })
  .done(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $('#dynamic-content').hide(); 
      $('#dynamic-content').show(); 
      $('#zonee').html(data.zonee);
     
      $('#modal-loader').hide();  
  })

Comment: above script only displays modal form but details not displyed.<div id="view-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
   <div class="modal-dialog"> 
      <div class="modal-content"> <div class="modal-body"><div id="dynamic-content"> <!-- mysql data will load in table -->
   <div class="table-responsive">
                             
                     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                     <tr>.....</table></div>

Comment: instead of adding code to comments here (which is ugly) , can you update your question with the above code and write some detail with it. thanks